# Why does the Flex compiler intermittently fails

Tags: apache-flex

We've got a large flex product.  When we compile it, either through Flash Builder or via ANT, we sometimes get this error:

```
[mxmlc] /nfs/projects/activities/rows/view/display/MToolsTutorialWindow.mxml(-1):  
   Error: Access of possibly undefined property document through a reference with 
   static type math.view.videoPlayer:VideoPlayer.
```

It happens a bit more than half the time.  Recompiling again, and sometimes it will work.  Often, you just need to go to that file, save it without changing anything, and compile to make it work.

The syntax is perfect with no weird dynamic types or anything like that.

It's baffling us.

Any ideas?

Comment: A note... we've seen similar behavior in the past on other projects and never solved it.  I don't believe it's particular to this codebase.

Comment: It happens to me once, I had to compile the module separately once, later I just included all used libraries in the `mxml` file (this is perfectly optimized by the compiler btw)

Comment: Which version of Flex are you using?  Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: Can you provide any more details about the structure of your code? Is the `MToolsTutorialWindow` class in a SWC or being loaded as module or anything like that? I'm surprised the ant build has this problem (not so surprised that the IDE does).

Comment: We're using Flex SDK 4.6 - The code is just in a normal.as file, no swc's - It sometimes happens in the main application, and sometimes it happens in modules that are compiled.  The source of the error (MToolsTutorialWindow.mxml) varies.

Comment: This doesn't make sense or explain your problem, but it's worth noting that Flex has it's own [VideoPlayer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VideoPlayer.html) class. I wonder if something funky is happening where these two similarly named classes are causing issues. Non-sensical, but that's all I got :)

Comment: We've got a potential solution.  It's possible that the flex compiler was running out of memory and failing in unique and interesting ways.  If we set the JVM mem arguments very low, it fails in a similar way quickly, and setting them very large makes the failure far less likely (maybe gets rid of it).  I guess there might be some faulty error handling in there for low-mem situations and our project has gotten big enough to hit it.